# How can I change an exist list, to a new list? || android - firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the exist “categories” list, to a new list.

I know that my problem is in the “setPriority()”, but I don’t find the right method.

My Database Structure:

[image]

My code:

```
private void updateData() {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();


            mDatabaseRef
                    .child("users")
                    .child(Login.userId)
                    .child("categories")
                    .setValue(categories)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                //Update success
                            } else {

                                //Update fail
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to query to database to update list. You can simply call `setValue` to over write the existing list with new one. Check below:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();

mDatabaseRef
    .child("users")
    .child(Login.userId)
    .child("categories")
    .setValue(categories)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                //Update success
            } else {

                //Update fail
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. How do you exactly write the ".updateChildren(categories)"? I mean, what do you write before?

Comment: Just replace `.setValue(categories)` with `.updateChildren(categories)`

Comment: I tried them both, and unfortunately both of them don't work. The "setValue", removes my list. Also, "updateChildren" stops my app.

Comment: If you have data inside `categories`, Then `setValue` should work. Avoid `updateChildren` as it's required `key-value` pair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207921/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-androidforeveryone).